# What does a "fixed size" image refer to in a font license?

Tags: fonts, licensing

What does it mean to license a font: "provided that the image is a fixed size"?

Example:

> Use the Desktop fonts to create images for commercial and non-commercial purposes on any surface such as paper, computer screens, billboards, T-shirts, and other surfaces without limitation on the print run, provided that the image is a fixed size.

"Fixed size" is not defined so is the idea to make sure the font does not deform when scaling the image disproportionately?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where this statement is used?

Comment: Which foundry is this font from? That sounds like a ridiculous clause in the license.

Answer (score 2):

This means "rasterized" (fixed resolution) or not scalable. In truth all things are scalable, regardless of format, but probably they mean that you are providing art to a print provider with the intention of it being a one-off for the specific purpose at a single size.

And "yes" this does imply that the use of the font in a vector-based logo is not allowed under the license, though one could argue that if you provide it and specify a print size, then you fulfill the requirement.

This is all legalese of course, and generally anything that is vague or ambiguous will favor the party who did not author the document.

Comment: Yea, sure sounds like some ridiculous licensing language written by someone that doesn't actually understand the industry.

Answer (score 2):

Once the font is turned into an image--be it vector or raster--it's no longer a font file. It's now just a shape or a collection of pixels.

I believe they are stating that the type can't be converted to vector format (which is infinitely scalable). But if that's what they mean, then one would wonder why they simply didn't state it that way.

Regardless, it's a rather ridiculous clause as this is what we as graphic designers use fonts for.

I'd contact the foundry for clarification and if they claim that you can not use their fonts in any vector based format, then ask them to kindly refund you the purchase price as you will be purchasing fonts elsewhere.